# JSF Saving get param to bean

Tags: jsf

I have a link  which gets me to kosz.xhtml?id=3;
How do i receive the id in  kosz.xhtml and save to bean?
`<c:set>` and `<f:param>` dont work for me

Comment: How are you using the <f:param>? It should be working

Comment: Get it worked with <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{kup.id}" />
</f:metadata>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that the `<f:viewParam>` is intented to be used. Put this in the template client:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</f:metadata>
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)